# rsync --link-dest not working over samba?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, rsync

I'm trying to wrap my head around `rsync` behaviour when using `--link-dest` as my personal backup.

My setup is a Mac Pro with a separate data partition which I want to backup to an ubuntu server.
Trying this with Time machine did not work out so far (last issue: wrong max target size of 46 GB).

I got the whole thing working with `rsync` over ssh and that's fine for me.

Last thing I tried was to make incremental backups using the `--link-dest` option.
I got it working via ssh (201_10_08 is a full backup)

```
rsync -avh --delete --link-dest=/mnt/backup_data/2014_10_08 /Volumes/Data/ user@host:/mnt/backup_data/2014_10_09
```

This works just fine with the `--link-dest` path pointing to the folder on the target system.

Now I tried to simplify this by defining `backup_data` as a Samba drive and mounting it from the Mac (updated rsync to 3.0.9 on the mac due to slow performance over samba of old version).

Result: Despite the same modification date, owner and group of the files on the mounted drive (as verified by `stat`), subsequent backups generate full backups and no hard links on the target system

I tried `--link-dest=/mnt/backup_data/old` (result: path could not be found, which makes sense since access is only to smb share not the whole target system) as well as `--link-dest=/Volume/mount/old` (with path via smb mount on mac, result: no hard links, full backup).

I can work with the solution I worked out, but I would like to understand the behaviour.

Anyone ideas?

Comment: Samba is emulating a Windows file server, you can't create Unix hard links on a share.

Comment: I see. I thought it might be something fundamental as this. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the rsync version shipped with OS X is not the most current one and you could be running into the following issue:

> Note that rsync versions prior to 2.6.1 had a bug that could prevent
>   `--link-dest` from working properly for a non-super-user when `-o` was specified (or implied by `-a`). 
>   You can work-around this bug by avoiding the `-o` option when sending to an old rsync.

Comment: This is another reason why I upgraded to rsync 3.0.9 on the mac. This is verified.

Comment: I overlooked that nugget in your original question. The comment by @user2210761 seems spot on.